# How do I play an MP3 file (many tracks in one file) with a cue file attached to it?

Tags: music, mp3

What player supports listening to long **MP3** files with tracks information in a separate ***.cue** file?

I tried **DeadBeef** v. 0.5.5, but without luck. It only supports lossless disc images, like **flac** or **avi**, as far as I understood.

[image]

Comment: What?  a .cue file is used to specify the location of tracks in a raw cd image, not an mp3, which should only be a single track.

Comment: I Just see what I see (attached an image). I downloaded the pack from torrents. If these files can not be played together, let me know.

Comment: Its normal to have a album in one big-size mp3 file with a cue file with it. You must split the mp3-file to get single-files for listening. Cue file is just information about the tracks and a split-program will then use the cue file for splitting the mp3 file in right lengths tracks. See answer under.

Answer (score 1):

You can install "mp3splt-gtk" from software center. With that application you can split the *.mp3 files into single files from the *.cue file.

To split it:

Click browse, and select the big mp3 file. Then click "File -> Import Splitpoints" then select the cue file. Then click "Split". In preference you can select output folder etc.

Comment: Not really what the question asked for, but a handy tip! Command line version worked easily for me: `mp3splt -c cuefule.cue input.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

Try Amarok:

> Amarok is a powerful music player with an intuitive interface. It
>   makes playing the music you love and discovering new music easier than
>   ever before and it looks good doing it! Amarok is based on the
>   powerful Qt4 / KDE4 Platform and nicely integrates with KDE desktop.

To install [**Amarok** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/amarok/)

Or if you like you can install from the terminal. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install amarok
```

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>